# Login with lightdm and home mounted from nfs server does not work

Tags: mount, login, lightdm, nfs

I try to install a Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop with LDAP authentication and `/home` mounted from a NFS server. Without the `/home` NFS mount everything works just fine. But with the mount after the login I get back to the login screen.

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct  8 20:29:38 w00 lightdm[1301]: ** (process:1611): WARNING **: Error reading existing Xauthority: Failed to open file '/home/foo/.Xauthority': Permission denied
Oct  8 20:29:38 w00 lightdm[1301]: Error writing X authority: Failed to open X authority /home/foo/.Xauthority: Permission denied
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
share.srv:/media/home                           /home           nfs     defaults,noatime        0 0
```

`/etc/exports` from NFS server:

```
/media/home             10.0.23.0/24(rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: Are your users' UIDs/GIDs the same on the local and remote systems?

Comment: No they are different. But even with a local ubuntu user which exists also on the NFS server it does not work.